# How do we add a new column in a spark dataset and populate it with some string value?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a function that creates a dataset with the columns as following : 
 type, dataType . 
This method is called iteratively in side a for-loop (containing columnNames).

```
for(String columnName : columnList){
    Dataset outputDataset = profile.process(inputDataset, columnName);
    //do some custom logic on this outputDataset
}
```

For each outputDataset created I need to add the columnName as an additional column into the dataset.

```
for(String columnName : columnList){
    Dataset outputDataset = profile.process(inputDataset, columnName);
    outputDataset = outputDataset.withColumn("newColName", new 
    org.apache.spark.sql.Column(columnName).cast("string"));
    //do some custom logic on this outputDataset
}
```

However , on doing this I get the following SparkAnalysisException:

```
'Project [dataType#103, name#104, type#105, cast('RowID as string) AS columnName#110]
+- LogicalRDD [dataType#103, name#104, type#105]
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`RowID`' given input 
columns: [dataType, name, type];;
'Project [dataType#103, name#104, type#105, cast('RowID as string) AS 
 columnName#110]
+- LogicalRDD [dataType#103, name#104, type#105]
```

How do I achieve this scenario?

Comment: Did u mean     profiledDataset = outputDataset .withColumn("newColName", new org.apache.spark.sql.Column(columnName).cast("string"));

Comment: Made the changes.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways of solving this , will enlist all of them :

1. **Using columns made of literal values in withColumn()**

   ```
         for(String columnName : columnList){
            Dataset outputDataset = profile.process(inputDataset, 
            columnName);
            outputDataset = outputDataset.withColumn("newColName", new 
            Column(Literal.create(columnName, DataTypes.StringType)));
            //do some custom logic on this outputDataset
           }
   ```

This , I believe is the optimum solution for the question I posted above. Besides this we can do crossJoin() as well as use spark-sql to project a new column to a resultant dataset